# Missing Package in AngularDart

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-pub

I try to use AngularDart according to the [AngularDart.com Tutorial](https://angulardart.org/tutorial/03-ch01-creating-your-first-app.html).
My `pubspec.yaml`:

```yml
name: test
description: A sample web application
dependencies:
  angular: "1.0.0"
  web_components: ">=0.8.0 <0.9.0"
  browser: ">=0.10.0+2 <0.11.0"
transformers:
- angular
```

Always when i run pub get, i get the following error:

> --- 09:24:30 Running pub get on D:\Bachelorarbeit_Projekt\Source\notices ... ---
>   Resolving dependencies...
>   Got dependencies!
>   Precompiling dependencies...
>   Loading source assets...
>   Loading di/module_transformer and smoke/src/default_transformer transformers...
>   Transformer library "package:di/module_transformer.dart" not found.

I tried with Eclipse plugin and Dart Editor. 
Have no more ideas...

Comment: Have you tried to run `pub cache repair` (on the command line)?

Comment: yaer, found this solution also. but i get error too if i use cache repair:D:\Bachelorarbeit_Projekt\Source\notices>pub cache repair
Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "C:\Users\bauer\AppData\Roaming\Pu
b\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\meta-0.8.8".    U know why he want to have pubspec.yaml in a different directoy?

Comment: Then you need to delete that directory. This is something `pub cache repair` isn't yet able to fix.

Comment: well... u are always right. thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pub cache repair` can't fix a broken cache in the case of a missing `pubspec.yaml` file.
In this case delete the folder of the faulty package within the `pub cache`.
This is a known issue (see http://dartbug.com/21418 and http://dartbug.com/21408)

Answer (score 1):

I deleted AppData\Roaming\Pub\ manually...

Then it worked

Answer (score 0):

I tried manually deleting the directory which still didn't work, then I did 'pub upgrade' which ended up working.

Comment: Yup, you need to run `pub upgrade` on all your projects to get the `.pub-cache` directory re-created and re-filled again.